# Prove that the diameter of a ball is smaller or equal to 2r

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(M,d)$ be a generic metric space.

Define $B_r(x)=\{y \in M : d(x,y) \leq r\}$

And $diam(A) = \sup \{ d(a,b) : a,b \in A\}$

To Show:
$$diam(B_r(x)) \leq 2r $$

---

How can I show this rigorously?

I have that :

$ diam (B_r(x))= sup \{ d(a,b) : a,b \in B_r \}$

Moreover, for $a,b \in B_r(x)$:

$d(x,a) \leq r$ and $d(x,b) \leq r$

Thus by properties of metrics:

$d(a,b) \leq d(x,a) +d(x,b) \leq 2r$

But then I am unsure how to use the supremum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a,b\in B_r(x)$, then
$$d(a,b)\le d(a,x)+d(x,b)\le 2r. $$

Answer (score 0):

2$r$ is upper bound of $\{d(a, b) :a, b \in B_r(x)\}$ since $d(a, b)\leq 2r \;\; \forall a, b \in B_r(x) $.

By definition of supremun, $sup\{d(a, b) :a, b \in B_r(x) \}\leq 2r $.        $\boxtimes$

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this question too, and I found the given answers somewhat terse. So here is my more long-winded answer, in case someone else ever searches this same question:

A quick review. The supremum of some set $A$ is characterized by two properties. First, $\sup A$ is an upper bound of $A$. Second, $\sup A$ is the least element in the set of upper bounds of $A$. Supremum proofs usually use both of these properties, and we'll use both in this proof.

Let $A = \{d(a,b) \mid a, b \in B_r(x)\}$. As the original post demonstrates, $2r$ is an upper bound of $A$. And also, $\text{diam } B_r(x)$ is an upper bound of $A$. This is because, by definition, $\text{diam } B_r(x)$ is the supremum of $A$, and the first property that characterizes the supremum is that it is an upper bound. Now, the statement $2r < \text{diam } B_r(x)$ is false, and this is because the second property of a supremum (e.g. diameter) is that it is the least upper bound. So since the statement $2r < \text{diam } B_r(x)$ is false, the statement $2r \geq \text{diam } B_r(x)$ is true, and that is the statement that was to be proved.